# Problem with ParseUser.logout() before fetch

Tags: android, parse-platform, fetch, logout

I'm using parse.com Android sdk, in the parseUser I have added a column pointer to other data class named pointer. I access this data by:

```
 ParseUser user=ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
 ParseObject pointer=  user.getParseObject("pointer");
                pointer.fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                    }
                 }
```

But I have a problem when I try to logout before doing this fetch. I logout by:

```
ParseUser.logOut();
```

and when this function is invoked the the app get locked.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to wrap this call to `fetch` in a check to see if there is still a logged in user:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // rest of your code here, as we have a currently logged in user
}
```

Comment: The current user isn't null, the problem is when I call `ParseUser.logOut();` before doing the `fetch` , the app get locked, and i need to kill it because it doesn't answer. If I comment the `fetch` then the `ParseUser.logOut();` works fine.

Comment: Calling `ParseUser.logOut();` will make the current user null, that's one of the things it does... if you have saved a reference to the current user (in your `Pointer` variable for example) then that is bad because you now have a reference to an object you don't have permission for.

Comment: Sorry, bu I think I 'm not explaining well . I understand what you say , but the problem isn't about `ParseUser`reference. I'm logged in the app and `ParseUser.getCurrentUser();` isn't null, then i do the fetch, and I get correct data, then I call `ParseUser.logOut();` and the app get locked. In contrast if  I'm logged in the app and `ParseUser.getCurrentUser();` isn't null, the I call  `ParseUser.logOut();` and it works fine, and the application continue its flow.

Comment: Yes, once you call `logOut()` you no longer have permission on the user, since you can only fetch a user if you are logged in as that user.

Comment: ParseUser.getCurrentUser() always returns back as null for me.